# Nginx and gunicorn err 403 on third-domain request

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, multi-tenant, http-status-code-403

In my nginx server i set my nginx.conf like this for using with gunicorn (and a django app):

```
server {
    server_name  *.mytest.io;
    root         /var/www;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  ~^(?<account>.+)\.mytest\.io$;
    root         /var/www;


#add_header Test $account;  

 # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/web/core/frontend/static/;
    }       

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        add_header P3P $account;
    }
```

now if i call mytest.io all is done, but if i call for example demo.mytest.io or demo1.mytest.io (i already configure on my dns demo and demo1 with the server ip) nginx return the error "403 Forbidden"

> [error] 27554#0: *27 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden

Why for main domain there are no problem and for subdomain request i get an error on the same location? (/var/www)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have two server blocks. A request to demo.mytest.io or demo1.mytest.io will match the `server_name` directive in this one:

```
server {
    server_name  *.mytest.io;
    root         /var/www;
}
```

You have no `index` or `try_files` directives in this block, so a request without a uri path is interpreted by Nginx as a request for the directory listing of your root directory.

You don't have an `autoindex` directive, and by default the value of this is set to `off` which prevents the listing of directory contents, so your request is denied.

A request to mytest.io doesn't match the `server_name` directive in either block, but the addition of `default_server` to the `listen` directive in the second block means Nginx will use this block to process any requests which do not match any other server blocks, so that request lands here.

The second block has a working set of directives, so it works.